# Trying to open new tab by right clicking on Web element but unable to

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It is right clicking for 'Shirt' element instead of 'Tshirt'. And after right clicking it does not perform the 'open new tab' operation.

Note: When it right clicks on the window, window moves a little down and select 'Shirt' element.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.flipkart.com");
IWebElement menHomePageElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title = 'Men']"));
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

Thread.Sleep(5000);

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/button[text() = '✕']")).Click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

IWebElement tshirtLinnk = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title = 'T-Shirts']"));
IWebElement shirtLinnk = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title = 'Shirts']"));
IWebElement kurtasLinnk = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title = 'Kurtas']"));

Thread.Sleep(3000);

action.MoveToElement(menHomePageElement).Perform();

Thread.Sleep(3000);

action.MoveToElement(tshirtLinnk).Perform();

Thread.Sleep(5000);

action.ContextClick(tshirtLinnk).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
```

[image: Element Trying to click]

[image: Item getting clicked]

Answer (score 3):

Can you cheat you way around with the following? Opens new window with required URL:

```
driver.Url = "http://www.flipkart.com";      
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._2AkmmA._29YdH8")).Click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#container > div > header > div.zi6sUf > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a > span"))).Perform();
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='T-Shirts']"))).Perform();

string nextLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='T-Shirts']")).GetAttribute("href");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('" + nextLink +"');");
```

Comment: I originally wrote a vba solution https://pastebin.com/uHc1sZ4N  so hope above transfers

Comment: Clean and perfect answer (+1)

Comment: It appears to be your answer :) you are the best judge. Getting upvoted means it was helpful !!!

Comment: @DebanjanB I rather hoped for some feedback from the OP! Though I appreciate yours. It was my first attempt at C# question.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> using Action and Sendkeys or by Robot framework java API. 
Then switch to the new tab by index and navigate to required url.